# javascript - API for the ipad touch keyboard

Tags: ipad, keyboard, touch

I'm developing a simple html-form for the ipad safari.

You can tab through the inputboxes via the "next" button on the touch keyboard. 
Unfortunatly one input box should have it's own "keyobard" (a spinnig wheel).

Is there any chance to hide the keyboard for this special input?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it not an `inputbox`, and use javascript to manipulate it like it is one. Use javascript to simulate the spinning wheel, and depending on what happens to it, change the `inputbox`.

Comment: Because then you can't "tab into" the simulated input element with the "next" button on the keyboard.

This would be a solution if I can manipulate the behavior of the keyboard and would work all right for me, but I haven't found an API for that yet.

Comment: Well I suggested this because there are no APIs to manipulate the keyboard as far as I know.

Comment: I already had nightmares about that ... ;-)
I don't exactly know, what I will do about this issue, but some answer will come by.

Comment: @barigorokarl:  I have a similar problem: a few necessary characters are missing from the standard keyboard, and neither are they present on the context-menu of the virtual keyboard; so I'd need something like a context-menu attached to the text-input, from which those few characters can be obtained and injected into the input.  What event would trigger the display of your custom keyboard? How would you insert characters into existing text at the caret position, or replace selected text with input from the custom keyboard? I have not found a solution yet.